# Entity Framework not writing to Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to take a JSON response, deserialize it, and store in a localdb.  Everything is working, but its not writing the data to my database.  I can't seem to figure out why its not as I'm not getting any errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DataFetcher.DataFieldsInClasses;
using DataFetcher.EF_Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace DataFetcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var teamNames = new TeamsList();
            teamNames.teamList.Sort();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                var cities = teamNames.teamList.ElementAt(i);
                //URL for each indivual team
                string URL = @"http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/" + cities + "/iphone/clubroster.json";
                WebRequest wrGETURL;
                wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(URL);
                HttpWebResponse response = wrGETURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                var result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                //var parsedInformation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
                foreach (var forwardData in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result).forwards)
                {
                    //test output
                    Console.WriteLine(forwardData.id + " " + " " + forwardData.position + " " + forwardData.name + " " + forwardData.twitterURL + " " + forwardData.height + " " + forwardData.birthdate);

                    //write to database using EF
                    using (var _temp_Player = new DataFetcherDBEntities())
                    {
                        //var players = _temp_Player.Set<Player>();
                        _temp_Player.Players.Attach(new Player
                        {
                            player_id = forwardData.id,
                            name = forwardData.name,
                            age = forwardData.age,
                            birthdate = forwardData.birthdate,
                            birthplace = forwardData.birthplace,
                            weight = forwardData.weight,
                            height = forwardData.height,
                            number = forwardData.number,
                            position = forwardData.position,
                            imageUrl = forwardData.imageUrl,
                            twitterURL = forwardData.twitterURL,
                            twitterHandle = forwardData.twitterHandle
                        });
                        _temp_Player.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Any tips/ideas?
P.S I'm still learning and self-taught.

*Edit, I copied the localdb to "...DataFetcher\bin\Debug\Databases" and my new error is ""Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__44DA120C6655986D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Player'. The duplicate key value is (8473492).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}"
Which doesn't make sense to me as every player has a unique ID (player_id = forwardData.id)

Comment: Use _temp_Player.Players.Add instead of Attach

Comment: Will try this right now.  
*edit
I checked the db using Server Explorer in Visual Studio and the table has nothing in it.  Also under Server Explorer, I had to Refresh as the localdb name had a 'Red' X beside its name.

Comment: Is the database currently blank? Can you check that in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Its not allowing me to open it in SQL Server Mange...

Comment: Is the primary key player_id in the database as well ?

Comment: yes it is, im going to try verifying the data doesnt exist.

Comment: you are getting a primary key violation which would suggest either the data exists or you are inserting duplicates

Comment: You could try emptying the table before the loop using this:

using (var _temp_Player = new DataFetcherDBEntities())
{
 _temp_Player.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Players]");
}

Comment: "Cannot find the object \"Players\" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use _temp_Player.Players.Add instead of Attach.

When you Attach, you need to set the entity state for the EF to detect that it is a new record and insert it into the database during Save Changes.

Comment: Check my comment above.

Comment: <add name="DataFetcherDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF_Models.DataFetcher.csdl|res://*/EF_Models.DataFetcher.ssdl|res://*/EF_Models.DataFetcher.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Databases\DataFetcherDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: It was already listed in Server Explorer as the database was created in Visual Studio.  And yes I do have it installed.

Comment: It should work with the Add. Can you update your code in the original post to show your updated code?

Comment: I switched .Attach to .Add

Comment: I don't know either and its frustrating me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75068/discussion-between-praveen-paulose-and-luca-tenuta).